# error NETSDK1032: The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win-x86' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible

Tags: .net-core

My Solution is:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29613.14
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Core31ConsoleApp", "Core31ConsoleApp\Core31ConsoleApp.csproj", "{06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {06477443-295A-47CA-A36E-A3F6B3AE47AC}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {17BBBF08-C7F4-4F6A-AD8F-32F2F3F21D27}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Console project is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This project contains only one C# "Program.cs" file which contains its default content:

```
using System;

namespace Core31ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, it's more or less new console app created for .Net Core 3.1. The only modification I did, is "Any CPU" architecture replaced with x86 and x64. It can be successfully built with VS for all combinations of Release/Debug and x86/x64.

When I try any of two following commands from cmd/powershell it also builds successfully.

```
dotnet build Core31ConsoleApp.sln --configuration Debug --runtime win-x64
dotnet build Core31ConsoleApp.sln --configuration Release --runtime win-x64
```

The problem starts when I try one of those two:

```
dotnet build Core31ConsoleApp.sln --configuration Release --runtime win-x86
dotnet build Core31ConsoleApp.sln --configuration Debug --runtime win-x86
```

They fail and following error message appear:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(151,5): error NETSDK1032: The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win-x86' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible.

This is minimal solution which reproduce this issue, but I have a much bigger and identically configured solution which fails a bit different way:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(151,5): error NETSDK1032: The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'win-x64' and the PlatformTarget 'x86' must be compatible.**

It fails for the first two commands and works for the second pair. It's probably because larger solution have different order in this section:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
    Release|x64 = Release|x64
    Release|x86 = Release|x86
EndGlobalSection
```

I'm working on Win 10 Prof machine (Intel's I7) with VS2019 and .Net Core 3.1 SDK (64-bit) installed during one of the recent VS updates. System and all the software installed is up to date.

I completely don't know what is wrong here or what I'm doing wrong.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

My error message was different but my fix may be applicable.  Error was:

```
The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'browser-wasm' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible.
```

The project is a Blazor WebAssembly project.  The csproj file had this in it:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I replaced the x64 with anycpu  which was suggested my another error message I got after I replaced the x64 with browser-wasm.  Ha.

Before the fix all my references/Dependencies in Solution Explorer had warning triangles on them.  And the markup was saying things like, I have no idea what DxDataGrid is. Do you need an @using statement.  That all went away after this fix.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a value to the node "RuntimeIdentifier" is not useful. Let me ask you, how did you load the COMMAND prompt? Did your taskbar or icon use a BATCH file? Did it use

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat
```

If so, you may be running "dotnet build" using the C++ command environment that is created by that batch file.

**ANSWER:**  do not use a VC++ Command Environment to run ASP.NET Core CLI.  Instead, use a Command Environment that is configured properly for ASP.NET Core CLI commands.  How do I know this? If you look at vcvarsall.bat, you will see, on line 71 to 75 of that batch file, the following gotcha:

```
@REM This temporary environment variable is used to control setting of VC++ 
@REM command prompt-specific environment variables that should not be set
@REM by the VS Developer Command prompt (specifically vsdevcmd\ext\vcvars.bat). 
@REM The known case this effects is the Platform environment variable, which 
@REM will override platform target for .NET builds.
```

Instead, use the one that came with VS2019, as in your Windows Start Menu. The command window should look similar to this:

[image: Visual Studio "boxed" Command]

Shown below, I compiled a WASM, and it works as long as you have the correct MS Build environment, which is set correctly in the VS 2019 Command Environment:

[image: Build Success! Use the Command Environment that comes with VS 2019]

Comment: For the VS 2019 CLI, the Command Window will correctly execute `dotnet run` and `dotnet build` functions properly.  You will also see a nice "Welcome" from window after the first time use.  It looks like this:  

`Welcome to .NET 5.0!`

Thanks to Scott Hanselman for Independent Injection, and to Microsoft for giving us the options to code!  Scott, take care of yourself and may you argue the params rightly everytime!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an executable try adding `<RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier>` in the TargetFramework Property Group.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier>  // add this
    <Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Project Setting -> Generate -> target platform -> AnyCPU  -> Save !  ok!

dotnet publish -r win-x86 -c Release --self-contained

dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to pdshuller's answer, I simply removed the `<PlatformTarget>` node from the project (.csproj) file, which did not match the `<RuntimeIdentifier>` value in the publish profile (.pubxml) file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>      
  <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
  <Configurations>Local;Development;Test;Production</Configurations>
  <!-- Removed this <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

My case:

1. Update by myself .net framework from 6 to 7 (because of project migration)
2. Then update the Visual Studio

then I get this error...

My own installation and .net SDK 7 seem to not work together correctly.

[image]

I uninstalled my own installation and left this from Visual Studio. All start working.